# OpenCV 3.0 source code installation troubleshooting

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I installed OpenCV3.0 using the source code obtained from itseez github repo. I set the install prefix as `/home/ubuntu/installed_libs/`. All went well. I even set ldconfig path in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/local.conf` and then `sudo ldconfig`.

However in my project (CMake) I cannot find the newly installed directory.

When I do `cmake ../` in the build directory it throws the following error.
I did some changes as suggested in the answers.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( DisplayImage )
set(OpenCV_DIR /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/share/OpenCV)
find_package( OpenCV )
add_executable( DisplayImage DisplayImage.cpp )
target_link_libraries( DisplayImage ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES} )

message(STATUS "OpenCV_FOUND=${OpenCV_FOUND}")
message(STATUS "OpenCV_INCLUDES=${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIR}")
message(STATUS "OpenCV_LIBRARIES=${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}")
message(STATUS "OpenCV_DEFINATIONS=${OpenCV_DEFINATIONS}")
message(STATUS "OpenCV_DIR=${OpenCV_DIR}")
```

Now `cmake` happens successfully.

```
 $ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Found CUDA: /usr/local/cuda (found suitable exact version "6.5") 
-- OpenCV_FOUND=1
-- OpenCV_INCLUDES=
-- OpenCV_LIBRARIES=opencv_videostab;opencv_videoio;opencv_video;opencv_ts;opencv_superres;opencv_stitching;opencv_shape;opencv_photo;opencv_objdetect;opencv_ml;opencv_imgproc;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_highgui;opencv_hal;opencv_flann;opencv_features2d;opencv_cudev;opencv_cudawarping;opencv_cudastereo;opencv_cudaoptflow;opencv_cudaobjdetect;opencv_cudalegacy;opencv_cudaimgproc;opencv_cudafilters;opencv_cudafeatures2d;opencv_cudacodec;opencv_cudabgsegm;opencv_cudaarithm;opencv_core;opencv_calib3d
-- OpenCV_DEFINATIONS=
-- OpenCV_DIR=/home/ubuntu/installed_libs/share/OpenCV
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/ubuntu/ctry/opencvtest/build
```

However, when I do a `make`, I get an error :

```
Scanning dependencies of target DisplayImage
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/DisplayImage.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable DisplayImage
CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/DisplayImage.cpp.o: In function `main':
DisplayImage.cpp:(.text+0x94): undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::string const&, int)'
DisplayImage.cpp:(.text+0x108): undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(std::string const&, int)'
DisplayImage.cpp:(.text+0x14e): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
DisplayImage.cpp:(.text+0x15e): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [DisplayImage] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I know this is a linking error. How should I fix this?

Verbose make display incase it is helpful.

```
$ make VERBOSE=1
/usr/bin/cmake -H/home/ubuntu/ctry/opencvtest -B/home/ubuntu/ctry/opencvtest/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/ubuntu/ctry/opencvtest/build/CMakeFiles /home/ubuntu/ctry/opencvtest/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ubuntu/ctry/opencvtest/build'
make -f CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ubuntu/ctry/opencvtest/build'
cd /home/ubuntu/ctry/opencvtest/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/ubuntu/ctry/opencvtest /home/ubuntu/ctry/opencvtest /home/ubuntu/ctry/opencvtest/build /home/ubuntu/ctry/opencvtest/build /home/ubuntu/ctry/opencvtest/build/CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/ctry/opencvtest/build'
make -f CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ubuntu/ctry/opencvtest/build'
Linking CXX executable DisplayImage
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++       CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/DisplayImage.cpp.o  -o DisplayImage  -L/usr/local/cuda/lib -rdynamic /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_videostab.so.3.0.0 /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.0.0 /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_video.so.3.0.0 /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_ts.a /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_superres.so.3.0.0 /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_stitching.so.3.0.0 /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_shape.so.3.0.0 /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_photo.so.3.0.0 /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so.3.0.0 /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_ml.so.3.0.0 /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.0.0 /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.0.0 /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.3.0.0 /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_hal.a /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_flann.so.3.0.0 /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_features2d.so.3.0.0 /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_cudev.so.3.0.0 /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_cudawarping.so.3.0.0 /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_cudastereo.so.3.0.0 /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_cudaoptflow.so.3.0.0 /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_cudaobjdetect.so.3.0.0 /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_cudalegacy.so.3.0.0 /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_cudaimgproc.so.3.0.0 /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_cudafilters.so.3.0.0 /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_cudafeatures2d.so.3.0.0 /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_cudacodec.so.3.0.0 /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_cudabgsegm.so.3.0.0 /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_cudaarithm.so.3.0.0 /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.0.0 /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so.3.0.0 /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_cudawarping.so.3.0.0 /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so.3.0.0 /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_cudafilters.so.3.0.0 /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_cudaarithm.so.3.0.0 /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_features2d.so.3.0.0 /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_ml.so.3.0.0 /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.3.0.0 /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.0.0 /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.0.0 /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_flann.so.3.0.0 /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_video.so.3.0.0 /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.0.0 /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.0.0 /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_cudev.so.3.0.0 /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib/libopencv_hal.a -ldl -lm -lpthread -lrt -lcudart -lnppc -lnppi -lnpps -lcufft -lcudart -lnppc -lnppi -lnpps -lcufft -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/cuda/lib:/home/ubuntu/installed_libs/lib 
CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/DisplayImage.cpp.o: In function `main':
DisplayImage.cpp:(.text+0x94): undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::string const&, int)'
DisplayImage.cpp:(.text+0x108): undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(std::string const&, int)'
DisplayImage.cpp:(.text+0x14e): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
DisplayImage.cpp:(.text+0x15e): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [DisplayImage] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/ctry/opencvtest/build'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/ctry/opencvtest/build'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: From the verbose output it seems that you're missing a `-L/path/to/opencv.so` argument in the compile line. You can fake it by setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the path to your opencv build result + its previous content.

Comment: But it also specifies the complete path, isn't it? /home/ubuntu/installed_libs. btw, I set the path using ldconfig. Checked `ldconfig -p` I am sure my custom paths for opencv listed before the default one. Am I getting you wrongly?

Comment: I'm not sure the `rdynamic` option is also setting the path to the library. You can check your configuration by compiling your program with a "hand crafted" command line (using pkgconfig to save some typing since its content seems ok).

Comment: pkg-config gives paths to the system installed opencv. But I think pkg-config (xxx.pc) and cmake (xxxConfig.cmake) uses different files to set configuration. Hand crafted one compiles by linking to system .so files. I have checked this with `ldd` on the executable. I really need to link to my custom .so files. I would also like to mention that my arch is arm-v7l.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the output of:

1. ldconfig -p | grep -i opencv
2. `pkg-config --cflags opencv`
3. `pkg-config --libs opencv`

If nothing is listed, then you `ldconfig` may configured incorrectly. If the system-installed version of OpenCV is listed, it may be a problem of the search order.

In either case, you could try to configure the `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` of your project `DisplayImage`, which is searched by CMake *before* standard system locations. So, assuming your in your build directory of `DisplayImage` is `$SRC_DIR/build`, configure your project like this

```
cmake -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH="/home/ubuntu/installed_libs/<OpenCV directory>" <other options> ..
```

Also interesting: [what happens in the background of `find_package()`](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries#How_package_finding_works).

Comment: Modified the cmakelist.txt. Now I get linking error

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
set(OpenCV_DIR /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/share/OpenCV)
```

to your CMakeLists, so it looks something like

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( DisplayImage )
set(OpenCV_DIR /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/share/OpenCV)
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED 3.0 )
add_executable( DisplayImage DisplayImage.cpp )
target_link_libraries( DisplayImage ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

Comment: Does not work commenting find_package(). Get the `undefined reference` error

Comment: sorry, please uncomment it. the `set(OpenCV_DIR ...)` command helps `find_package` knows where to look at.

Comment: still getting "CMake Error at /home/ubuntu/installed_libs/share/OpenCV/OpenCVConfig.cmake:214 (message):
  opencv_3.0 is required but was not found
"

Comment: Current version on github is 3.1.